# std::vector insert without knowing the type of the elements

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Suppose I have a templated function that takes various kinds of vectors (but for various reasons I can't mention this in the template parameter). Here's what I'm trying to do: insert a new, default constructed element at a specific spot, without knowing its type:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T* v) {
  v->insert(v->begin() + 5, decltype(v->at(0))());
}
```

This doesn't work, but gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do. I also tried to use `value_type` from `std::vector` but I ran into problems there as well. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should get an error that's hopefully descriptive of the problem. For example, GCC says, "error: value-initialization of reference type"

Comment: `v.insert(v.begin() + 5, decltype(v)::value_type() );`

Comment: @RichardCritten That's not going to work, and it's too much work; we can already use `T`

Comment: _"takes various kinds of vectors (but for various reasons I can't mention this in the template parameter"_ It would help to specify _what_ these reasons are. _"This doesn't work_" It would be germane to explain _why_ - what the error was. _"I ran into problems there as well"_ ... **what** problems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sidestep the whole "name the type" business:

```
v->emplace(v->begin() + 5);
```

or

```
v->insert(v->begin() + 5, {});
```

Your current version doesn't work because `decltype(v->at(0))` is a reference type. `value_type` should work if you use it correctly, but without seeing what you are doing I can't say what's wrong with it.

Comment: Probably `value_type` is being used like so: `v->insert(v->begin() + 5, T::value_type{})` when it would need to be used like so `v->insert(v->begin() + 5, typename T::value_type{})`

Comment: Follow up question: what if I *do* have to call a static function on the value type of the vector? Then I do need the type, right? Say: `decltype(v->at(0))::Bar()`, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: `std::remove_reference<decltype(v->at(0))>::type::Bar()`. If you don't care about enforcing the static-ness, the usual `.` syntax can be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you know `v` is always a `std::vector` of some element type, then just type it that way to begin with, so `T` is the element type, not the vector type:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(std::vector<T>* v) {
  v->insert(v->begin() + 5, T());
}
```

That also ensures that `v->insert()` and `v->begin() + 5` are valid statements.  You original code allowed *anything* to be passed for `v`, so there was no guarantee that `v->insert()` and `v->begin()` exist, or that `begin()` returns a random-access iterator that accepts `+ 5`.