# Calling class function on templated container member

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

I'm trying to call a static function on a member of a vector inside a templated function. But I can't get the code working. I get the error: ‘Do’ is not a member of ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type& {aka A&}’ Any ideas?

```
struct A {
  static void Do() { cout << "Hey.\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T* v) {
  decltype(v->at(0))::Do();
}

int main() {
  vector<A> v;
  foo(&v);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44189845/stdvector-insert-without-knowing-the-type-of-the-elements?noredirect=1#comment75393783_44189845

Comment: so why are you asking this if you way your previous question (40 min earlier) obtained a valid answer to this one too? Actually from the same person answering here again.

Answer (score 3):

```
T::value_type::Do();
```

Or

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(v->at(0))>::type::Do();
```

Or

```
std::decay<decltype(v->at(0))>::type::Do();
```

Or if you don't care about enforcing static-ness (and know the vector to be nonempty):

```
 v->at(0).Do();
```

Comment: Nit: the last version doesn't work if the vector is empty, so I do need staticness.

Comment: @LajosNagy But you don't need to call `at(0)`, you can use `operator[]`, i.e. `(*v)[0].Do();`, which even for an empty vector should work (since the element referred to is not used).